# Import TypeScript file from node_modules package in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

Currently, I'm working on a simple Angular project (v14). In this project I'm using a (private) NPM package that contains only 1 TypeScript file. This TypeScript file has a exported class but I'm unable to use it when importing them in my Angular component. The class is always undefined and returns this error:

```
TypeError: package_test_class__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.TestClass is not a constructor
```

I have created a class and import that class in a component as seen below.

**test-class.g.ts** (in node_module package folder)

```
export class TestClass {
    name = 'test';
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestClass } from '@package/test-class';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log(new TestClass());
    }
}
```

I have copied the `test-class.g.ts` file from the `node_modules` folder into the `src` folder of the project. When I import it from this location the class is initialized as expected. However, this is not how I want to use this file, since that would mean I have to copy it after every update.

What is the best way to use classes from TypeScript files in NPM packages? Looking forward to any advice.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to the answer if you specified the package, in case anyone has experience of if the package needs a specific way of initialization.

Comment: The package in question is a custom package. It contains only the test-class.g.ts file that I want to import and use in a component.